# How can I fix the strange spacing and justification in this document to maximise space?

Tags: multicol, wrap

I'm designing a crib sheet so even though it's messy, I want the math to "run together" and wrap like normal text, within each column. So far, though, I haven't made it work yet as the image shows.

[image]

This is my MWE. Not completely minimal but I hope the idea is clear. The problem occurs in list item 1, but for slightly shorter chunks of math (as in item 3) there isn't a problem.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section} {\normalsize \bfseries \color{red}} {\thesection}{0em}{}
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\newrobustcmd{\parens}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
\newrobustcmd{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert{#1}\right\rvert}


\renewrobustcmd{\P}{\mathbb{P}}
\newrobustcmd{\convp}{\stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\jot}{0pt}
\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep}
\setlist[enumerate]{nolistsep}

\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=*}



\begin{document}
{\small
\begin{multicols}{3}

\section*{Convergence in probability}
$X_n \convp X$ if $P\parens{\abs{X_n - X} \geq \epsilon} \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$
$X_n \convp X$ if $P\parens{\abs{X_n - X} < \epsilon} \to 1$ as $n\to\infty$

How to prove
\begin{enumerate}
\item Direct proof: $\P\parens{\abs{X_n - X} < \epsilon} = \P\parens{-\epsilon < X_n - X < \epsilon} = F(\epsilon) - F(-\epsilon)$
\item \begin{equation*} a = b \end{equation*}
\item This is long text that includes notation $a = b = c + \int_a^b x F_n(x)$
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum

\end{multicols}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (Off-topic, but) if you are eager to save space, don't reinvent the wheel: use `savetrees`.

Comment: `\parens` prevents wrapping, replace by `()` to wrap at the end of the line.

Comment: @Marijn That fixed the wrapping problem; thank you!

Comment: @jon I didn't know about the `savetrees` package, but it's extremely helpful for what I'm trying to do. I was definitely reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @MichaelA -- Cheers! (I thought that might be the case).